# Unable to connect from Java to kafka running inside docker container

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka

I am very new to kafka and docker, and I want to connect from Java to Kafka running inside the docker container, but I get an error, and it seems to be a lack of networking knowledge from my side.

I have defined an env variable: `KAFKA_HOSTNAME=kafka`

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '1.1'

networks:
  sb:
    driver: bridge

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    container_name: zookeeper
    hostname: zookeeper
    networks:
     - sb
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka
    hostname: ${KAFKA_HOSTNAME:-kafka}
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    networks:
     - sb
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: ${KAFKA_HOSTNAME:-kafka}
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://${KAFKA_HOSTNAME:-kafka}:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

When I run the `docker-compose up`, I can see that the zookeeper and the Kafka broker are started successfully:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                              COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                        NAMES
60460c26ef86        confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest       "/etc/confluent/dock…"   19 minutes ago      Up 19 minutes       0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp                       kafka
0d1fd4000a83        confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest   "/etc/confluent/dock…"   19 minutes ago      Up 19 minutes       2888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, 3888/tcp   zookeeper
```

Here is my simple java program I try to run:

```
private static final String bootstrapServers = "192.168.0.102:9092";

//create producer properties
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());

//create producer
KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);

//producer record
ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord("first_topic", "hello from java");

//send data
producer.send(record);


producer.flush();
producer.close();
```

In the docker logs I can see that it is creating the `first-topic` inside the kafka container, but in the Java program I get the following error:

`[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error connecting to node kafka:9092 (id: 1 rack: null)
java.net.UnknownHostException: kafka`

I have a few questions:
1. What am I missing?
2. How should I correctly set the `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` property in docker-compose file? Is it correct to hardcode the IP?
3. How should I correctly set the `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS:` property?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

if you are running on mac
try KAFKA_HOSTNAME=docker.for.mac.localhost

on windows
try KAFKA_HOSTNAME=docker.for.win.localhost

Comment: the same unknown host exception: kafka

Comment: @AndrewT Because you are setting the advertised name to `kafka`

Comment: so how would it be correct to map it?

Comment: @AndrewT If you want your machine `localhost` to continue to sent requests to `localhost`, then the container needs to "advertise" as `localhost`. Same logic can be applied to an IP address or host name. But `kafka` (the container service name) isn't known to your external DNS server, so that is why it'll fail unless your producer code is also in a container.